# XCode link error: Unsafe mutable addressor

Tags: xcode

My app was working great until about two hours ago when I got a link error regarding an unsafe mutable addressor.

What I've tried:

Clean and build, deintegrated and reinstalled my cocoapods, deleted derived data, restart XCode, restart Mac

None of this has helped. Can anyone tell me from the error text what the problem is?

Ld /Users/eligarfinkel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Zoomoji-habngemvvlqbmiajrhdkufqvpnis/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Zoomoji.app/Zoomoji normal (in target 'Zoomoji' from project 'Zoomoji')
cd /Users/eligarfinkel/Documents/Zoomoji
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -target arm64-apple-ios15.4 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.5.sdk -L/Users/eligarfinkel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Zoomoji-habngemvvlqbmiajrhdkufqvpnis/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.5.sdk/usr/lib/swift -F/Users/eligarfinkel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Zoomoji-habngemvvlqbmiajrhdkufqvpnis/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -F/Users/eligarfinkel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Zoomoji-habngemvvlqbmiajrhdkufqvpnis/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/SwiftSpeech -F/Users/eligarfinkel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Zoomoji-habngemvvlqbmiajrhdkufqvpnis/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/SwiftySound -filelist /Users/eligarfinkel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Zoomoji-habngemvvlqbmiajrhdkufqvpnis/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Zoomoji.build/Debug-iphoneos/Zoomoji.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Zoomoji.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker /usr/lib/swift -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @loader_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -dead_strip -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /Users/eligarfinkel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Zoomoji-habngemvvlqbmiajrhdkufqvpnis/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Zoomoji.build/Debug-iphoneos/Zoomoji.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Zoomoji_lto.o -Xlinker -export_dynamic -Xlinker -no_deduplicate -fembed-bitcode-marker -fobjc-link-runtime -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos -L/usr/lib/swift -Xlinker -add_ast_path -Xlinker /Users/eligarfinkel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Zoomoji-habngemvvlqbmiajrhdkufqvpnis/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Zoomoji.build/Debug-iphoneos/Zoomoji.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Zoomoji.swiftmodule -framework AVFoundation -framework Foundation -framework SwiftSpeech -framework SwiftySound -framework Pods_Zoomoji -Xlinker -no_adhoc_codesign -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/eligarfinkel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Zoomoji-habngemvvlqbmiajrhdkufqvpnis/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Zoomoji.build/Debug-iphoneos/Zoomoji.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Zoomoji_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/eligarfinkel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Zoomoji-habngemvvlqbmiajrhdkufqvpnis/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Zoomoji.app/Zoomoji

Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
"unsafeMutableAddressor of self #1 : Zoomoji.ContentView in Zoomoji.ContentView.body.getter : some", referenced from:
closure #3 () -> () in closure #1 () -> SwiftUI.TupleView<(SwiftUI.Text, SwiftUI.Button<SwiftUI.Text>, <<opaque return type of (extension in SwiftUI):SwiftUI.View.onAppear(perform: (() -> ())?) -> some>>.0, SwiftUI.ModifiedContent<SwiftUI.ModifiedContent<SwiftSpeech.SwiftSpeech.RecordButton, SwiftSpeech.SwiftSpeech.ViewModifiers.RecordOnHold>, SwiftSpeech.SwiftSpeech.ViewModifiers.OnRecognize>)> in closure #1 () -> SwiftUI.TupleView<(<<opaque return type of (extension in SwiftUI):SwiftUI.View.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(SwiftUI.Edge.Set) -> some>>.0, SwiftUI.VStack<SwiftUI.TupleView<(SwiftUI.Text, SwiftUI.Button<SwiftUI.Text>, <<opaque return type of (extension in SwiftUI):SwiftUI.View.onAppear(perform: (() -> ())?) -> some>>.0, SwiftUI.ModifiedContent<SwiftUI.ModifiedContent<SwiftSpeech.SwiftSpeech.RecordButton, SwiftSpeech.SwiftSpeech.ViewModifiers.RecordOnHold>, SwiftSpeech.SwiftSpeech.ViewModifiers.OnRecognize>)>>)> in Zoomoji.ContentView.body.getter : some in ContentView.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. I had a double instantiation of a variable. Once I deleted that, the app compiled normally.